# How can I check that all object's fields with default value were set?

Tags: scala, default-value, case-class

Most of time default values are very suitable, but in some cases I want to check that they were set manually.

Example

```
//most fields with default value
case class Person(
  name: Option[String] = None,
  name2: Option[String] = None,
  bithYear: Option[Int] = None      
)


object OtherPersonToPersonConverter {
  def convert(other: OtherPerson): Person = {
    Person(
      name = other.name,
      name2 = other.name2,
      bithYear = other.bithYear 
    )
  }
```

Then I added another field with default value

```
case class Person(
  name: Option[String] = None,
  name2: Option[String] = None,
  bithYear: Option[Int] = None,
  city: Option[String] = None
)
```

I should fix the converter, but I don't know about this because of default value usage. Is there any way to create an object without usage of default values (and produce compilation time error)?

Comment: hard to understand what and why you need since you rejected Jatin's answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just:

```
case class Person(
  name: Option[String] = None,
  name2: Option[String] = None,
  bithYear: Option[Int] = None,
  city: Option[String]
)
```

Comment: That code generate compilation time error on every creation of Person, but needed only some of them (with special way of construction object? may be)

Comment: so use the compilation error to find the code that needs updating and then add back the default value... what's wrong with that?

Comment: In that case programmer not forced to do that. He simply edit Person class and forget about it. I'm looking for a way to force him to edit dependent class even if he uses default values

Comment: @paul_di That is why the above will work as the compiler wont let him compile successfully if he forgot to add. He will need to set a value necessorily.

Comment: I understand that. But in fact we have many usages of Person and only some of them need editing with modifying class. There is no way to tell other programmer: "you must fill all fields only there and there". Typically programmer which edited that scared by tens usages (and compile errors) and produce default empty value

Comment: I am sorry then I dont get the question. If you do not wish compile time error then what is it that you exactly need to force the developer to fill it? Seems to that you dont want it to happen at all instances but only some. But on what basis do you define `some`?

Comment: @paul_di, there is no surefire way for anyone else (such as the compiler) to tell the programmer where they should fill the fields in, in their old code, because when they wanted to fill all the values in, they used `Person(...)`, and when they wanted to use default values, they also used `Person(...)`. Only the programmer can know which is which. All you can really do now to fix old code is to search through it, and this answer provides a way to start that search, by triggering compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can create as many constructor functions as you'd like. A good place to put them is in the companion object:

```scala
object Person {
  def create(name: Option[String], name2: Option[String], ...): Person = Person(
    name = name,
    name2 = name2,
    ...
  )
}
```

The constructor function `Person(...)` is equivalent to `Person.apply(...)`, that is, calling the `apply()` method of the companion object, so you're just making another one by defining `Person.create()` (or whatever you want to name it). By creating multiple constructor functions, one with default values and one without, you can control whether or not the default values are used when you create your `Person` instance by choosing which method you call.

If it works better for you, you could make `create()` be the one with default arguments, and not define default arguments for `apply()` (that is, in the `case class` definition).

Comment: It is close to solution. In separate function you still invoke default apply wich support default values. But it is strange for any other programmer to edit class and not to fix companion object.

Comment: Well, you need to make some decisions in your code. If you use `case class`, then the default `apply()` will be called on all object creations (even if you use `new`). So if you want to be able to create an object without the possibility of default values, you must either (1) have the default apply be the one without default values, and a different method be the one with default values, or (2) not use the `case class` syntax, so that `new Person(...)` does not call `Person.apply()`, and then manually implement the functionality you want that `case class` would have given you.